# Background image not showing -Android

Tags: android, eclipse, background-image

I have written a Catching Fire Countdown app that has a background image.  I had the image placed in all Drawable folders.  I removed them so the file wasn't so large and I received complaints that the image no longer showed.  I put the images back, the app updated, and I'm still being told that the picture isn't showing up on certain devices.  Nexus 7 is one of them and Galaxy tab II are the 2 recent ones I've heard about.  Instead of my image it is just a black background.

Any idea why?  How can I get an image to display on EVERY device?

I was reading something about tablets, the image, and it being a possible out of memory thing?  Does that sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: You sure you haven't changed the name of the image?

Answer (score 2):

Put your set of image in every following folder

**drawable-mdpi

drawable-ldpi

drawable-hdpi

drawable-xhdpi**

After looking into drawable-mdpi,drawable-ldpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi.Last place where the Android OS looks for the Image if it is unable to find that image, is the **drawable** folder  So try placing the image in it also and see if it works.

Comment: The drawable folder is for older devices (pre 1.6). This can't be the issue with the Nexus 7 but it's worth being aware of.

Comment: Ok thanks!  I'll look when I get home (at work now).  I do believe that I have the picture in all of those folders, although it might not be in the xhdpi.  It's times like this where I wish I had set up logmein on my home computer! haha.  thanks again!

Comment: Hey Yeah I have an image in all drawable folders.  It's even showing up on my nexus 7 emulator but it isn't on the person's tablet :-\

Comment: Please go through this link and see if you have missed something...

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html

Comment: I'm wondering, per the link, if the nexus 7 is unable to stretch the image correctly and therefore it doesn't display it. Does that sound about right to you?  Any ideas on how I can take an already created image and make it nexus 7 compatible?   **Also** the image shows on my nexus 7 emulator.  Any idea how to make a true nexus 7 emulator?